# How to transition from drywall covered fiberboard?

Tags: drywall, insulation

I'm planning to insulate and sheetrock my garage. Surrounding the door going into the house is some type of fiberboard that's about 15/16" thick. As you can see in the photos, the distance from the edge of the stud to the face of the 1/2" drywall is 1 7/16". If I'm going to add sheetrock to the attached wall, how should I handle that 15/16" space to line up the drywall?

I was thinking I could rip some strips from 2x4 construction lumber to shim the studs out a bit, but I'm not sure if that's the best option. Would it make more sense to buy matching fiberboard and screw the drywall through that?

[image: Wall Width]
[image: Wall]

Comment: Hi Shane, Since its a matter of look, its opinion based and it is more decorating  than home improvement.

Comment: Wait, so you have the fiberboard *and* some drywall around the door already?  Do you know if there's insulation behind the fiber?

Answer (score 3):

Insulate the cavities, and if you can't get 15/16" Homasote® (which is probably what you have) put 1" (assuming 15/16" will be hard to find there, which I think is correct) foam sheets over, followed by drywall, and deal with the 1/16" differential in mudding the finish at the joint where the two meet.

Comment: I was trying to think of how to get an actual 1" board, because there isn't many options between 3/4" and 1.5", other than two sheets of 1/2" with another 1/2" sheet over it. That would be a bit excessive..... **Foam**, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Attach sheetrock to the studs. Use a piece of wooden molding (or 2 pieces) to cover the transition.

Or, rip off the old fiberboard, so you have an even surface to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Adding strips of wood to level the substrate is a perfectly acceptable solution.